# Solving multiple linear equations using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have what I think is a very interesting problem here but have little idea how I can go about solving it computationally or whether a Python dataframe is appropriate for this purpose. I have data like so:

```
    SuperGroup   Group  Code  Weight Income
8   E1           E012   a     0.5    1000
9   E1           E012   b     0.2    1000
10  E1           E013   b     0.2    1000
11  E1           E013   c     0.3    1000
```

Effectively, 'Code' has a one-to-one relationship with 'Weight'.

'SuperGroup' has a one-to-one relationship with 'Income'.

A SuperGroup is composed of many Groups and a Group has many Codes.

I am attempting to distribute the income according to the combined weights of codes within that group so for E012 this is `(0.5*0.2 = 0.1)` and for E013 this is `(0.2*0.3 = 0.06)` As a proportion of their total, E012s becomes 0.625 `(0.1/(0.1+0.06)` and E013s becomes 0.375 `(0.06/(0.1+0.06)`.

The dataframe can be collapsed and re-written as:

```
    SuperGroup   Group  Code  CombinedWeight Income
8   E1           E012   a,b   0.625          1000
10  E1           E013   b,c   0.375          1000
```

I am capable of producing the above dataframe, but my next step is to apply the weights to the income to distribute it in such a way that it averages to 1000 still but reflects the size of the weight of the group it is associated with.

Letting `x=0.625 and y=0.375 then x=1.67y`

Additionally, `(x+y)/2 = 1000` **note: my data often has several groups present in a supergroup so it could be more than 2 resulting in a system of linear equations if my understanding is correct**

Solving simultaneously produces 1250 and 750 as the weighted incomes. The dataframe can be re-written as:

```
    SuperGroup   Group  Code  Income
8   E1           E012   a,b   1250
10  E1           E013   b,c   750
```

which is effectively how I need it. Any guidance is warmly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we `agg` the DataFrame on `['SuperGroup', 'Group']`

```
res = (df.groupby(['SuperGroup', 'Group'])
          .agg({'Weight': lambda x: x.cumprod().iloc[-1],
                'Code': ','.join,
                'Income': 'first'}))
```

Then we re-adjust the Income within each SuperGroup with the help of `transform`:

```
s = res.groupby(level='SuperGroup')
res['Income'] = s.Income.transform('sum')*res.Weight/s.Weight.transform('sum')
```

---

```
                  Weight Code  Income
SuperGroup Group                     
E1         E012     0.10  a,b  1250.0
           E013     0.06  b,c   750.0
```

Comment: `.reset_index()` and `.drop(columns='Weight')` if those are unnecessary at the end, but those steps are peripheral to the main logic.

Comment: Wow! Superb solution and so concise. Thank you so much!

Comment: I've realised now that multiplying weights isn't the best thing to do because of the varying length of Codes present within a Group, so a mean average would be better. How can the lambda function be adapted to do this instead?

Comment: I guess I can get the cumulative summed weight but how do I get the length of codes within that group to divide by?

Comment: @user3058703 you can change the aggregation to `mean` instead of the `lambda` when I define `res`. This slightly changes the answer to 1166 , 833 respectively. Or perhaps you just want `sum` as the aggregation, so that in the final step the income for each Group gets weighted by the proportion of total weight within each Supergroup

Comment: Wow that simple! Pandas is awesome